# How to distribute $x \times \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I distribute the x in this problem?

How do I "gain access" so to say. Does it become $x^\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + 1)^\frac{1}{2}$ or $(x^3+x)^\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Or do I need to even do that in order to integrate $\int x(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: When you deleted the dollar signs in your edit you eliminated all the math formatting.  A tutorial on MathJax is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  In your original post you didn't mention integration.  Please ask the question that you really care about. There are many ways to transform $x\sqrt{x^2+1}$ and if we know the purpose we may be able to suggest a useful one.

Comment: Understood, I'll try to be more specific in future posts and will learn MathJax.

Comment: You don't need to distribute it man to integrate, you are making you life more complex this way !!

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$$

If $x\ge 0$, then $x=|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ leads $$x\sqrt{x^2+1}=\sqrt{x^2}\cdot\sqrt{x^2+1}=\sqrt{x^2(x^2+1)}.$$
If $x\lt 0$, then $x=-|x|=-\sqrt{x^2}$ leads$$x\sqrt{x^2+1}=-\sqrt{x^2}\cdot\sqrt{x^2+1}=-\sqrt{x^2(x^2+1)}.$$

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks for the complete answer

Answer (score 2):

$x\sqrt{x^2+1} = \dfrac{x(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=(x^2+1)\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}}$

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is non-negative (i.e. $x\geq 0$), then
$$x\sqrt{x^2+1}=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2+1} = \sqrt{x^2(x^2+1)}=\sqrt{x^4+x^2}, $$
if this is what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to expand in order to integrate. Just use a $u$ substitution with $u = x^2 + 1$ and so $du = 2x \space dx$ and so $dx = \frac{du}{2x}$ and so
your integral becomes $$\large{\int \color{red}{x}u^\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{du}{2\color{red}{x}}}$$ and so you cancel out the $x$ to end up with $$ \large{\int u^\frac{1}{2} du = \frac{u^\frac{3}{2}}{ \frac{3}{2}}} =\frac {2u^\frac{3}{2}}{3}=\frac{2(x^2+1)^\frac{3}{2}}{3} + C$$

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks for catching my formatting errors.  Sorry I can't upvote this post my reputation is below 15.

Comment: You are welcome :)
I don't care about votes man :) I care about helping others